# Django admin panel converts None type data to empty string

Tags: python, django

Any edit made to an object in the django admin panel changes all string fields having `None` to empty string i.e. `''`.

Is there a workaround or does it requires changes in the django code itself.

Django version: 1.8.5

Comment: what's your model ? Might be those converting is normal because that fields are char fields ? Add `null=True` for those fields

Comment: Yes it is a char field and why is it normal?

Answer (score 2):

My guess is that problem within field definition in model, add `null=True` to allow storing null values within database.

From [Django Model field reference#null](https://docs.djangoproject.com/es/1.9/ref/models/fields/#null):

> If True, Django will store empty values as NULL in the database.
>   Default is False.

Comment: Adding `blank=True` only allows the user to enter empty values from the user interface and has nothing to do with the actual database representation. It is even explained in the link you suggested.